# Keras - How to classify 1D time series

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras, time-series

Say I have a training dataset composed by 128 1-Dimensional time series in form of numpy arrays.

They all correspond to a certain action that I label `action_1` and I want to recognize.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish the following taks:

- Train a model with the training dataset (the 128 1-D numpy arrays)
- Ask the model to predict the action in a new test entry (a 1-D numpy array)

This is my very first attempt at Machine Learning, thank you in advance for any indications.

Comment: This is a really interesting read http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/01/10/using-deep-learning-to-listen-for-whales and might give you some pointers. This also is a more modern post https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/10/acoustic-detection-of-humpback-whales.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what's your question exactly. If you are interested in the model architecture time series are the typical example for using RNNs (recurrent neural networks) or some more advanced form of them i.e. LSTM or GRU. They are all implemented in keras (https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/).

You may also can experiment with CNNs (convolutional neural networks). Usually they are used for images but in certain cases they can even outperform RNNs. They are also implemented in keras. (https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/)